# How to make PPM packages from CPAN

Tags: windows, perl, activestate

I want to create my own binary PPM packages on Windows from CPAN modules.

There is `PPM::Make` which does it pretty well.

But also there is `CPANPLUS` which has plugins to create native binary packages for distributions (e.g. `.deb` or Arch Linux `.pkg.tar.xz` Pacman)

Is there a CPANPLUS plugin to create PPMs? Are there any other methods/frontends to create PPMs conveniently?

Answer (score 1):

[How2 - create a PPM distribution - 0.2](http://jenda.krynicky.cz/perl/PPM.html)